# Table widths hugging elements

Tags: css

I'm working on a site for one of my in-laws, who insisted on using Joomla so that he could update the content himself in the future.  That being said, one of the things that I developed for him was a character generator for a game that he and his brothers created.  That is working fine.  The issue is that they want a way to print the final sheets off when finished, and to do so without all of the menus, banners, etc.  I was told that the simplest way to handle that was to pass `?tmpl=component` in the URL to strip everything out, which is also working.

The problem that I am running into is that the CSS in the Joomla template is causing the tables to behave in a way that I cannot figure out how to correct.  The page consists of nested tables, with widths defined in terms of % (currently), but it seems that the specifically defined widths are being ignored in favor of the widths hugging the largest cell.  To see what I'm talking about:

The trouble page: http://www.basementgames.com/tools/character-generator.html?s=36&tmpl=component

What the page should look like: http://www.basementgames.com/char_gen.php?s=36

This is the *exact* same code in both places, with the first being inside Joomla, and thus subject to the CSS of the template.  I don't know much about CSS, and I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out what to override to make the first example look like the second.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You're always better off posting the relevant markup, css and/or JS in the question itself.

Comment: When you remove this stylesheet: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/bgma3/css/print.css" type="text/css" />`, the page displays like you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what CSS is causing the problem, otherwise I'd be able to override it, and the file created by Artisteer (which is what was used to create the template) is fairly long.

Comment: Run this while on the page in the [Firebug or Chrome Console Command line](http://getfirebug.com/commandline): `document.getElementsByTagName('link')[5].remove();`

Comment: It seems that IE doesn't like that kind of change.  Firefox took it with no problems, thought.

Comment: Try this (and view source): http://jfcoder.com/test/printable.html

Comment: Yes, apparently IE 8 and lower don't support the `.remove()` method. Hmm...

Comment: Ok, try that link to my site again. I updated the script to zero out the `href` element of that `link` element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help here!  I've been bashing my head against this for the last week.  That appears to have done the trick.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, try this one (it's geared more to run only on that page with the `tmpl=component` in the query string: http://jfcoder.com/test/character-generator.html?tmpl=component

Comment: That page winds up calling itself a bunch of times, and is broken down into a number of sections, each with it's specific role.  Section 36 ( `?s=36` ) is the only part that is supposed to be outside of the Joomla template, and so has that code inserted there.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this script on the page and it will remove the offending `print.css` file on page load:

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/character-generator.html') > 0 &&
    window.location.href.indexOf('tmpl=component') > 0) {
    (function(){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            if (links[i].href.indexOf('/print.css') > 0) {
                links[i].href = '';
            }
        }
    })();
}
</script>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/character-generator.html?tmpl=component

Note, it only runs on the `character-generator.html` page with a `tmpl=component` in the query string. It also has to run *after* the `link` elements, as well, so it should be inserted into the `body` tag or at the very bottom of the `head` tag. Since you have MooTools available, you could also use [`DOMReady()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DOMReady).